# The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle. for android studio 1.1.0

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I am trying to clone my project but i am getting error

```
The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Target Gradle project look like,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'//actual its 0.12+ i change to 2.2.1+
    }
}

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

allprojects {
    version = VERSION_NAME
    group = GROUP

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-reporting'
```

Local project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nanda.myapplication01"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.github.eluleci:flatui:3.0.0'
}
```

my graddle.wrapper

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

tried change dependency.Still having same issue and Checked so many solution but its not fixing;Please help me to resolve.Thanks in advance.

Comment: repositories {
       jcenter()
    } i tried manually but still i have error

Answer (score 0):

The version of Android gradle plugin needs to be compatible with the version of Gradle. Checkout the version compatibility [mapping table](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)

[image].

Comment: And my project supports all theses creteria